# Android Air GoViral ANE showFacebookShareDialog throwing modeOverride error

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, air, ane

I'm trying to implement Facebook sharing using Milkman's GoViral ANE.

On the device the app sets up GoViral, the user logs in using Facebook, permissions are granted (including "publish_actions" permission).

The call to goViral is as follows:

`goViral.showFacebookShareDialog("My name", "My caption", "My description", "<app url on the play store>");`

However I'm seeing this runtime error when the sharing code runs:

```
I/<app id>(25773): ArgumentError: modeOverride parameter must be a valid member of GVFacebookDialogMode.
I/<app id>(25773):  at com.milkmangames.nativeextensions::GoViral$/assertArgs()[D:\data\svn.milkmangames\trunk\ane\goviral5\swclibrary\src\as3\com\milkmangames\nativeextensions\GoViral.as:1734]
I/<app id>(25773):  at com.milkmangames.nativeextensions::GoViral/showFacebookShareDialog()[D:\data\svn.milkmangames\trunk\ane\goviral5\swclibrary\src\as3\com\milkmangames\nativeextensions\GoViral.as:727]
```

I'm stumped.

Setup:

- AIR 23.0
- Android 4.4.2
- GoViral 5.6.0 (latest version as of Dec 2017)
- Facebook API 2.5

Answer (score 0):

That would suggest to me that some of the libraries are out of date.
Try using the latest versions of the ANE and AIR SDK if possible.

GoViral 5.6.0
AIR SDK 27 (or 28 on labs.adobe.com)

Comment: Thanks @crooksy88. I am using the latest version of the ANE, but still seeing the same error after updating Air SDK to 27.0